# The arabic font is too small to read

Tags: feature-request, fonts

the arabic font is too small to read. i have to strain my eyes to read it in the current state.
I can zoom the brower to read it but zooming everytime is not a point.

In the normal state the font looks like this
[image]

Zoomimg it upto 190 to 200 % makes it clear.
[image]

Doing that everytime is not feasable.
Suggest a solution for this.

Comment: you can change the size of fonts for different fonts in your browser's settings. I haven't use Opera recently so you may want to check their help site or ask a question on [su].

Comment: If/when the site makes it out of beta, it will get its own theme, including CSS. It would probably be trivial to include a larger default font size for Arabic text then.  Before then, I'm not sure what options exist.

Answer (score 2):

In Question and Answer, we can have them to a more legible format by applying some styling on the fonts as below; which is the one that looks good?

1. ستاق اكثجىنج  (Default size, hard to read)
2. **ستاق اكثجىنج** (Same size, bold but readable?)
3. *ستاق اكثجىنج* (Same size, italic and readable comparitively)
4. ## ستاق اكثجىنج (Header #1, much readable!)
5. ### ستاق اكثجىنج (Header #2, not bad)
6. #### ستاق اكثجىنج (Header #3, seems like pt. 2)

We might need to encourage users to make their arabic more readable by applying the styling (and so, mention about this in the FAQ or something?) or perhaps some automatic process could be introduced..

Maybe we can just use some other fonts?

I've also noted that in the chat room, arabic is extremely hard to read because of its restricted size. Maybe we can tell everyone to apply the above styles since markdown is supported in chat?

Comment: In the third point i just see boxes. seems to be font problem on my side. what font are you using for the 3rd?

Comment: @Ashu That's weird, its all the same font. IDK which one I just have arabic on my windows 7.

Comment: @Ashu you need to add Arabic support to your OS first.

Comment: @ashes999 i already have those fonts installed but still the third point is nothing but block-spaces.

Comment: Looking around i seem to find that i have a problem with the italic font **on opera only** it appears clearly on firefox

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if [TeX support](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2/revisions) was added to Math.SE only 9 days after it's launch (including private beta). Therefore, I think we could get the SE team to fix this problem up for us.

Regarding implementation, it'd be great if the software detected Arabic characters (Unicode >0xFF, and all that); otherwise, we could adopt markup similar to:

```
$$[insert Arabic text]$$
```

Also, consider that font size of Arabic text is dependent on what fonts you have installed on your system.

Comment: see this http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-about-we-use-latex-in-this-community

Comment: @Ashu Haha, I'm not asking to add TeX support here, of course; I was just using that as an example of what happened at a different SE site. :)