# Please add a right-to-left, right-aligned display option for Arabic quotes

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, arabic, markdown

Quran quotes tend to be written in Arabic, which is written right-to-left; writing this left-to-right is awkward.

Also, increasing the [size of the font](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/the-arabic-font-is-too-small-to-read) would help with readability.

Comment: You might find the suggestions here helpful: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88/right-to-left-formatting-for-hebrew

Comment: Note also that there's a standing request on MSO for RTL support in Markdown (Stack Exchange's formatting language): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/will-there-be-rtl-support-in-stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

We have a kinda-sorta solution for [Hebrew](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198666/1438) on Judaism and Biblical Hermeneutics.  There aren't currently plans for a [virtual keyboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192318/1438) for Arabic because we are waiting to see how the Hebrew keyboard is received.

One thing that made supporting Hebrew a lot easier was that a user [wrote a userscript](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195/integrated-hebrew-virtual-keyboard/1781#1781) prototype.  In fact, HodofHod's script is *more* featureful than the official version.  (Thankfully, it's possible to use both at the same time to compare them.)  It should be possible to fork the [Hebrew keyboard](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/SE-HebrewKeyboard.user.js) and alter it into an Arabic keyboard.  I can't make any promises that Stack Exchange will integrate it, but such a solution should help users who are willing and able to [install userscripts](http://userscripts.org/about/installing).