# Arabic text issues

Tags: feature-request, arabic, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible right to left option be added for Quran verses?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/is-it-possible-right-to-left-option-be-added-for-quran-verses)

This includes issues from [this question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/the-arabic-font-is-too-small-to-read) and [this question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/is-it-possible-right-to-left-option-be-added-for-quran-verses)

Can we get some language support for Arabic in posts please?

1. The most important thing is the right alignment of paragraphs and the `rtl` direction attribute for paragraphs in Arabic.
2. Then the ability to edit Arabic in the text box - right now all the letters are disconnected from each other and it's really ugly (but it shows up OK outside the text box).
3. Finally, an increase in the default text size for Arabic would be most appreciated.

For #2 above, this is what I see in Ubuntu and Chrome: [image]

Comment: point #2 is OS related. if your system supports right to left languages then you will be able to edit Arabic in the textbox.

Comment: I can edit Arabic text fine in other places. It's just this textbox which causes all the letters to be disconnected from each other.

Comment: That's weird, May I know your OS and browser? I have just tested this on IE, FF, Chrome and Safari and it seems fine...

Comment: @HaLaBi Oh interesting - I use Ubuntu and Chrome.

Comment: I tested that on Windows 7. I will test it on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Checked on Ubuntu and firefox.. it is working fine. check this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb7lt.png

Comment: @HaLaBi edited posted to include screenshot

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your particular set up, I don't think this is general problem. It also works fine for me.

Comment: Since the bulk of this request seems to be issues which are unique to your machine / computing environment, I'm closing this as a duplicate of the earlier request (which I've edited).