# Using images for Quranic verses

Tags: discussion, images

I've noticed a number of users have been embedding images into their questions and their answers, wherein the images consist of nothing more than the Quranic text itself.  Presumably this is due (in part) to the fact that [Arabic text can be very hard to read](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/the-arabic-font-is-too-small-to-read) on the site.

Yes, adding the images does make things more legible, but it also has a *very serious* drawback: **Text that is in image form is unsearchable**. As we're striving to make a repository of questions and answers not only for ourselves but for *all future users*, the ability to easily search through existing posts is at least as important as having them look good to the end user.

And that's not getting into other issues that copious text-image use can cause, especially (but not limited to) when dealing with devices with limited bandwidth, screen size or memory (e.g., mobile devices).

Images should be used to complement the text of the post, but never to replace it.

Comment: What about using the alt text of the image element to store the Arabic text of the ayah?

Comment: I think the main issue (at least for me) is readability; that's why I use images, no text. Images are not easily reformatable, either.

Comment: Is anyone really going to search for Quranic text? Being an English-based site, I think the translations for the text suffices. I would agree that the translations shouldn't be given in images, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to watch out for is that images may not scale well to mobile devices. The ones from Quran.com are very large and clear, so it scales comfortably to the mobile version of the site, but anything much smaller than that won't be as clear.

Answer (score 0):

We need better support for Arabic script, unfortunately from my experience this sort of thing will only happen once we're out of beta, insha Allah. I wonder if the mods from SO have any alternatives for us in the mean time?